# How to Convert CSS Grid Template Columns to Rows Responsively

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to display a 3 column layout on desktop and a single column layout on mobile using CSS Grid.

However, when I try the following a 3 column layout persists with a viewport smaller than 650px.

```
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 34% 33%
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}
```

How do I transition between a 3 column wide layout to single column stacked layout responsively with CSS Grid?

Comment: share a full code

Comment: If you want a three column layout, with equal-width columns: `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)`

Comment: Have you tried to use JavaScript in the page to check the device-pixel-ratio (`alert(window.devicePixelRatio)`)? In many phones - those with Retina, or greater, screens - the device-pixel-ratio is higher than 1, which means that there are 2, or 3, or more 'real' pixels to each 'css pixel' (I know, I know). This means that the `max-width` test isn't accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `repeat()` for this and just set the columns to one frame for the media query.

```
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `grid-template-area` property as follows:

```
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-area: "a b c";
  grid-template-columns: 33% 34% 33%
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-area: 
      "a"
      "b"
      "c";
  }
}
```

Where string delimiters denote new rows.

Comment: The first answer didn't work in the context of my layout. Furthermore, "repeat" has nothing to do with converting grid columns to grid rows, as far as I can tell.

So, this is the correct answer for me. I solved my mobile form layout this way. I don't know why it was voted down. Maybe because an important detail is missing.

The areas are named here as a, b, c. These names must also be used in the columns (respectively rows) with "grid-area: 'a';" and so on.